# Dynamic number of UIViews in custom UIView

Tags: ios, uiview, quartz-2d

I'm making a custom UIView. It holds a bunch of UILabel objects as its subviews. The count of UILabel objects is unknown at creation time. Which method in should I initialize these UILabel objects? Is drawRect suitable for this job?

Answer (score 0):

No, `drawRect:` is not suitable. `drawRect:` is for drawing the content of the view, not modifying the subviews of the view. You should update based on the triggering event - perhaps `viewDidLoad`, `viewWillAppear:`, or some user event like them pushing a button. If your triggering event is on a background thread then you need to switch to the main thread before adding the new labels as subviews.